# Entity framework one-to-many relationship - how to rename foreign key name when it is named Id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I'm trying to create a one-to-many relationship between the asp.net identity table "aspnetusers" and my own "application" table. The problem is that the aspnetusers table primary key does not have a name prefixing it - it is just named "Id".  I'd like to create a name for it such as ApplicationUserId, so that I can avoid confusion when using it for binding purposes.  How can I do this?

```
public class Application
{
public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

//**Need the aspnetuser table Id property here for my foreign key and would like to name it   ApplicationUserId - how do I do this?
```

Comment: Either I or the other two answerers miss your point. Aren't you just simply asking how to map `aspnetusers.Id` (as column) to `ApplicationUserId` (as property)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just add a virtual property to your `Application` class, EF should take care of naming the FK in the database and you'd just be accessing that navigation property from your code, i.e. you won't need to know the FK column name in your code. But if you insist on specifying it, you can try something like this in your class:

```
public class Application
{
    // other properties

    public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User {get; set; }
}
```

and in your DbContext class use fluent API and override  `OnModelCreating` method with something like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Application>()
                    .HasRequired(x => x.User)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.ApplicationUserId);
    }
}
```

NOTE: I didn't test this, so customize this to fit your needs specifically.

Comment: Could you provide an example of just adding a virtual property?  Would this work?  public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser {get; set}

Comment: Yes, I believe that would work, if `ApplicationUser` is the correct type, both tables are in the same database and `ApplicationUser` is in the same DbContext. However, good practice is to separate the Identity and application databases, in which case you'd just be storing the ApplicationUser and its ID property as a "loose" property which would not be "physically" related in the database.

Comment: In case identity and application databases are separate, the above discussion becomes irrelevant ;)

Comment: This did create the foreign key and named it ApplicationUser_Id.  For binding purposes, do I use this name or the navigation property?   For instance I have a dropdown list with: ViewBag.FullName = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "FullName", application.ApplicationUser);

Comment: I always prefer using navigation properties where possible.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like

```
 public class Application
{
public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

[Required]
[DisplayName("First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Last Name")]
public string LastName { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("aspnetusers")] 
[Column("Id")]
public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

public virtual aspnetusers aspnetusers {get; set; }
....
```

Comment: For some reason it's saying that "aspnetusers" isn't a valid navigation property.

Comment: I added the virtual navigation property in my answer,